# R Select XML attributes from child elements and generate a data frame

Tags: r, xml

I simply cannot get my head around how to make the childelements in a element as rows and the attributes in them as columns in a R dataframe for the XML structure seen below.

I know how to do it when the elements are in the root. Like:

```
data <- getURL(url) %>%
  xmlTreeParse(., useInternal = TRUE) %>%
  xmlRoot()
doc <- XML::xmlToList(data)
nodes <- grep("SubChild2_1", names(data))
out <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(nodes, function(x) doc[[x]])), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For this:

```
<Child1 filename="stuff" datetimecreated="date stuff" datetimeimported="stuff" stuffi="s" >
  <SubChild1_1 attri1="attri1v" attri2="attri2v" />
  <SubChild2_1 IMPODATE="2019-02-22" IMPOVALUE="1" IMPOVALUE2="123.35" IMPOVALUE3="12.85" />
  <SubChild2_1 IMPODATE="2019-02-22" IMPOVALUE="2" IMPOVALUE2="654.35" IMPOVALUE3="23.85" />
  <SubChild2_1 IMPODATE="2019-02-22" IMPOVALUE="3" IMPOVALUE2="789.35" IMPOVALUE3="34.85" />
</Child1>
```

But I struggle to find out how to look one step into the xmltree like for this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<response xmlns="http://www.xx.com/abc/def" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xx.com/abc/def http://www.xx.com/abc/def.xsd" status="1" timestamp="2019-03-06T20:24:14">
 <Child1 filename="stuff" datetimecreated="date stuff" datetimeimported="stuff" stuffi="s" >
  <SubChild1_1 attri1="attri1v" attri2="attri2v" />
  <SubChild2_1 IMPODATE="2019-02-22" IMPOVALUE="1" IMPOVALUE2="123.35" IMPOVALUE3="12.85" />
  <SubChild2_1 IMPODATE="2019-02-22" IMPOVALUE="2" IMPOVALUE2="654.35" IMPOVALUE3="23.85" />
  <SubChild2_1 IMPODATE="2019-02-22" IMPOVALUE="3" IMPOVALUE2="789.35" IMPOVALUE3="34.85" />
 </Child1>
</response>
```

Could anybody help me with that rather small annoying problem.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014515/r-xml-combining-parent-and-child-nodesw-same-name-into-data-frame/55025203#55025203

Comment: Have you used `rvest`?

Comment: No haven't tried rvest but the xml. didnt know of rvest so i will try to look into that one.