# Converting a nested XML document to a data frame, when information is both in attribute and text nodes

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

**Background:**

I have an XML document with the following structure:

```
<records>
 <record id="512" size="1">
  <user id="8412" origin="ab"/>
  <category id="105">Certificates</category>
  <rating>80</rating>
  <text>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </text>
 </record>
 <record id="452" size="2">
  <user id="7623" origin="bb"/>
  <category id="105">Certificates</category>
  <rating>70</rating>
  <text>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </text>
 </record>
</records>
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

Using R, I'm trying to convert this XML information into a dataframe, where each row represents a single record, and each column represents either attribute or text data for that record (with the goal of including all the data that exists in the XML document).

This is what the final output should look like:

```
Record ID | Size | User ID | ... | Text           |
       452|     2|     7623| ... | Lorem ipsum... |
```

Also, since there are around 1,000,000 records, and the file containing them is ~500MB, I'm trying to find a relatively efficient way to do this.

**What I've tried so far:**

I've looked at a number of related questions on the topic, but none of them offered a solution that applied in this case.

First, I tried using the 'xmlToDataFrame' function in the XML package using the following code, but it's only extracting the text data, and not the attributes:

```
library(XML)
doc = xmlParse("My_document.xml")
xmldf = xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = "//record")
xmldf = xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//record"))
```

The same happens when I try to use the flatxml package, despite the fact that during the initial import of the XML document it does extract the relevant attribute data:

```
library(flatxml)
doc = fxml_importXMLFlat("My_document.xml")
xmldf = fxml_toDataFrame(xml_original, siblings.of = 2)
```

I also tried a slightly different approach using the xml2 package:

```
library(xml2)
doc <- read_xml('My_document.xml')
rows <- xml_children(doc)
data.frame(
  Record_ID = as.numeric(xml_attr(rows,"id")),
  Size = as.numeric(xml_attr(rows,"size")),
  User_ID = as.numeric(xml_attr(rows,"id")),
  Origin = as.character(xml_attr(rows,"origin")),
  Category = as.character(xml_text(rows,"category")),
  Category_ID = as.numeric(xml_attr(rows,"id")),
  Rating = as.numeric(xml_text(rows,"rating")),
  Text = as.character(xml_text(rows,"text"))
) -> xmldf
```

Here I had a different set of issues: I'm able to extract attribute data, but only from the 'record' node. This means that it copies the 'id' data from the record for the 'User_ID', and is unable to access the relevant data for things such as the 'origin' attribute. In addition, this process also pulls all the text information from all nodes simultaneously each time I attempt to extract it.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014515/r-xml-combining-parent-and-child-nodesw-same-name-into-data-frame/55025203#55025203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider binding attributes with the internal method, `xmlAttrsToDataFrame`, and elements with `xmlToDataFrame`, assuming only one set of *user* and sibling tags per *record*.

```
library(XML)
...

# BIND ATTRIBUTES AND ELEMENTS
record_df <- cbind(XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, path='//record')),
                   XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, path='//user')),
                   xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//record"))
             )    

# RENAME COLUMNS
record_df <- setNames(record_df, c("record_id", "record_size", "user_id", "user_origin",
                                   "record_user", "record_category", "record_rating", "record_text"))

record_df
#   record_id record_size user_id user_origin record_user record_category record_rating              record_text
# 1       512           1    8412          ab                Certificates            80  \nLorem ipsum dolor ...
# 2       452           2    7623          bb                Certificates            70   \nUt enim ad minim ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the most part. The only issue is that it doesn't extract the category_id attribute (which I believe you saved under 'record_user'), and simply leaves an empty column there. I added the following line to the code in the cbind function: XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, path='//category')), and now it does extract this information, though for some reason it still also extracts an empty column immediately after it. Any idea why?

Comment: It is because *user* is an empty node, only carrying attributes.